# How to make my function find my excel table?

Tags: python, excel, list

I am trying to run through an excel file line by line and create a new list and then append every cell value on that line to the list. I don't think my code is correct but I just want to know why it cannot find the file, this is the error message.

```
def createPersonList(fileName):
   open(fileName)
    i = 0.0

    for line in fileName:
        i += 1
        Person = []
        for cell in line:
            Person.append(cell)
            return Person
```

**error message:**

```
  createPersonList(personData.csv) Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-36-207031458d64>", line 1, in <module>
  createPersonList(personData.csv) NameError: name 'personData' is not defined
```

Comment: Do you want to open an excel or csv file? In any way you need some library that read the file for you. e.g.: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: You forgot to put the filename in quotes. You should rather call `createPersonList('personData.csv')`

Comment: is the personData.csv in the same directory as your python script? If not use the absolute path to the personData.csv. As @FaizanNaseer mentioned you also have to input the file path as a string in to your function, otherwise python thinks the function argument is a variable, therefore the NameError.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well what you want, and also i don't know your structure of file.
But that's something similar with what you want:

```
import csv
def createPersonList(fileName):
    personList = []
    with open(fileName, 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
        next(csv_reader, None)
        for row in csv_reader:
            for column in row:
                personList.append(column)
    return personList
```